# Cannot find my app on Google Play

Tags: android, publish

I've uploaded my app 20 minutes ago, and from everything I've read it is supposed to be able to be directly linked to almost instantly. When I do a direct link to the website it should be at, it says it is not found. I clicked the publish link in Developer Console, and it says it is published and available for 2000+ devices. Am I just being impatient? I just did a few searches online and the posts I've read said it should be available instantly, and since this is my first published app I'm wondering if I did something wrong. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

The package name is com.jessenorris.gpacalculator

I've tried searching for it with this link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jessenorris.gpacalculator

Comment: it takes around 2 hours(max), check later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you are ready, click the Publish button in the Developer Console. Within a few hours, your app will become available to users and your product page will be appear in Google Play for browsing, searching, or linking from your promotional campaigns.

From the documentation on developer site http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html#final-checks